# Is it possible to create a custom format/blot with complex substructure?

Tags: quill

I'm investigating the use of Quill for a project, and I need to know if it's possible to create a custom format/blot with more complexity than a single element and a single parameter.

An example of one of the layouts I want would be:

```
<span class="format-container">
    <span class="format-info" data-attr="param 1 (non-displayed)">
        param 2 (displayed to user -- click to invoke application UI to edit)
    </span>
    <span class="format-content">
        User's text/child elements go here
    </span>
</span>
```

In all cases I'm looking into, the custom formats are of inline scope and still have a single parent container and a single place for the child content to go.

Custom formats in Quill don't seem to be very well documented at the moment. I poked around in the sources and was able to figure out that this most likely isn't possible in 0.20.1. However, I feel like it could be doable in the 1.0.0 beta w/ Parchment, I'm just not sure on the specifics of what I'd actually need to write.

So is this possible in 1.0.0? If so, how could it be done?

**EDIT:** This is what I'm going for: [image: Example]

Comment: Interestingly enough I have almost the exact same requirement. I tried an Embed however it always forced my content onto a new line of its own, which was infuriating. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I spent a bunch of time digging around in the source code of the library and I actually don't think it's possible. Despite Parchment being a DOM "abstraction" it still relies on DOM parent/child relationships in places, meaning having child elements in a sub-container like this could break things. In the end, I just reworked my own formatting system so it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So, I figured out how to do this in the end with minimal effort. It involves defining a new blot type for Quill 1.3 or greater, the same code should work on older versions however is untested.

See the code snippet for a working example. The crux is to extend the existing Embed blot 'blots/embed' and define your own toolbar handler to inject arbitrary DOM node instances.

```js
// utility function used to inherit non prototypical methods/properties
function extend(target, base) {
  for (var prop in base) {
    target[prop] = base[prop];
  }
}

// definition of a custom Blot.
(function(Embed) {
  'use strict';

  function Span() {
    Object.getPrototypeOf(Embed).apply(this, arguments);
  }

  Span.prototype = Object.create(Embed && Embed.prototype);
  Span.prototype.constructor = Span;
  extend(Span, Embed);

  Span.create = function create(value) {
    return value; // expects a domNode as value
  };

  Span.value = function value(domNode) {
    return domNode;
  };

  Span.blotName = 'span';
  Span.tagName = 'SPAN';
  Span.className = 'complex';

  Quill.register(Span, true);
})(Quill.import('blots/embed')); // import the embed blot. This is important as this is being extended

// custom handler for the toolbar button
var handler = function() {
  var complexSpan = document.getElementById('complextype').firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  var selection = quill.getSelection();

  quill.insertEmbed(selection.index, 'span', complexSpan);
}

// instantiate quill. Note that modules.toolbar.handlers has a 'span' handler. Quill parses this from // the class on the button in the toolbar markup: 'ql-span' this is 'ql-' + blotName
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: {
      container: '.toolbar',
      handlers: {
        'span': handler
      }
    }
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

```css
:root {
  --complex-bgcolor: #767676;
  --font-color: #FFFFFF;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

button.ql-span {
  width: 15rem !important;
}

.complex {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid black;
  margin: 0.3rem;
}

.inner {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: var(--complex-bgcolor);
  color: var(--font-color);
  padding-left: 0.6rem;
  padding-right: 0.6rem;
}

.formatting {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nested {
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.1/quill.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.1/quill.snow.css" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="toolbar" class="toolbar">
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-bold"></button>
      <button class="ql-italic"></button>
      <button class="ql-underline"></button>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-span">Complex Span Type</button>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div id="editor">Lorem Ipsum 
    <span contenteditable="false">
      <span class="complex" spellcheck="false">
        <span class="inner">Format applied</span>
        <span class="nested">More text</span>
        <span class="formatting">with formatting</span>
        <span class="nested">dolor</span>
      </span>
    </span> sit amet
  </div>
</div>

<div id="complextype" style="display:none;">
<span contenteditable="false"><span class="complex" spellcheck="false"><span class="inner">Format applied</span><span class="nested">More text</span><span class="formatting">with formatting</span><span class="nested">dolor</span></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll admit that I eventually switched to a different RTE framework entirely, so I can't directly test this anymore. I don't remember seeing "handlers" when I went digging around. So either it was added recently or I just plain missed it. Glad you got this working! If you can give me a Plunkr/JsFiddle/some other working example, I'll happily accept this answer so others can find it more easily.

Comment: @StephenCohen I've edited my answer and provided a functional code snippet. And to be fair, missing custom handlers wasn't difficult, I had to dig for a fair few hours to work it out. Quill is a great project but the documentation is spotty in places.

Comment: Nice! I can see that it's still not perfect, (if you allowed the user to put arbitrary content inside the span, it wouldn't be editable after the format was applied), but it does technically do what I was trying to do and it works, so here's your green checkmark!

Comment: I was struggling to find a way to paste it inline, and discovered your answer. Turns out I only needed to change my import from `blots/block/embed` to `blots/embed`. What is life?

Comment: @KenoClayton Life for people like us is the constant and ongoing process of converting caffeinated beverages into weird and wonderful things that make magic witchcraft devices to do things.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this effort! Very helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielLane, for the example. I'd implemented a very similar blot, but I was running into issues where paste always used the new blot (instead of plain paragraphs). It turns out setting a good `[blot_name].className` property is vital. Otherwise Quill is overly aggressive in interpreting pasted text as a `div` or `span`.

Comment: @DanielLane thank you for the code you provided. But the problem with this code is that it makes circular structure and makes it unable to be serialized.
if you use `JSON.stringify(quill.getContents())`, you get this error:


"Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLSpanElement'
    |     property '__blot' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'blot' -> object with constructor 'Span'
    --- property 'domNode' closes the circle"

Answer (score 1):

Documentation and guides are still being written but a good place to look is how existing custom formats are implemented. The formula format in particular seems very similar to your use case.

Comment: I looked at that and there are key differences. The biggest of which being that Formula is an Embed whereas I need an Inline Blot that can have normal child content. Basically, the outer span renders a border, the first child span renders a bit of metadata text, and then the user keeps typing with their input going into the second child span. I'll edit my question with a mockup image that might be clearer.